# Device Width and Height Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity3D for which I need to create new objects at runtime. But I don't know how to determine their position so that they don't go outside the screen.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know where on the screen an object is displayed? In that case [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) should do the job. That is, something along the lines of

```c#
Vector3 screen_position = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
```